# What does "4-universal hash function" mean?

Tags: algorithms, hash-function, universal-property

I encountered the notion of 4-universal hash function and I cannot understand what exactly it means.
This article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing did not really help to clarify it.

Thanks!

Comment: what did you not understand ? the concept of universal hash function or the construction of an example of it ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the jargon around this is not consistent. 4-universal hashing is [4-independent hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-independent_hashing).

Note that there is no such thing as **a** 4-universal hash function - k-independence and k-universality are a function of families of hash functions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a pretty standard definition of a k-universal hashing, as stating [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.118.8806&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

What is says is that if you pick any K elements in the first set, choosing uniformly a hash function from the reference K-universal family will imply a uniform distribution over all combinations of K elements in the second set.

From an informational-bayesian perspective, this means that observing any k-1 hash results won't give you any information about the k'th value: $P(h(x_k) | h(x_{k-1})...h(x_1)) = P(h(x_k))$.